# Using ASyncTask to Draw Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask, android-studio, wear-os

I followed the online tutorial and created a class like so:

```
    public class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
        private int data = 0;

        public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
            // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }

        // Decode image in background.
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            data = params[0];
            return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), data, 100, 100);
        }

        public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

            // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

            // Calculate inSampleSize
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
        }

        public int calculateInSampleSize(
                BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
            // Raw height and width of image
            final int height = options.outHeight;
            final int width = options.outWidth;
            int inSampleSize = 1;

            if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

                final int halfHeight = height / 2;
                final int halfWidth = width / 2;

                // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
                // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
                while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                        && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                    inSampleSize *= 2;
                }
            }

            return inSampleSize;
        }



        // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
                final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                if (imageView != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }

        public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView imageView) {
            BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
            task.execute(resId);
        }

    }
```

Now that I created the "ASyncTask" class, I do not know how to apply it.

What I need to do is simple. I need to draw the bitmap like so (it is set up so that it will do it every second):

```
canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, centerX, centerY, null);
```

How do I apply ASyncTask now so that I will draw this bitmap without doing too much work on the thread? Please help, much appreciated.

Comment: Your asynctask takes care of decoding the bitmap, just execute it and have your bitmap decoded and stored, ie. in myBitmap. From then on, you will draw your bitmap in the onDraw() function. The onDraw function triggers each time you call invalidate(), so if you need to draw your bitmap every second, you'd need to call invalidate() every second.

Comment: I think ASyncTask isn't the right choice for something like that.

Comment: What is better? I'm trying to use it because that's the only thing I was able to find.

Comment: @Rupps how is that supposed to be done specifically?